# RestSharp Unit Test NUnit Moq RestResponse null reference exception

Tags: c#, moq, restsharp

I'm having some challenges trying to use Moq with RestSharp.  Maybe it's it my misunderstanding of Moq but for some reason I keep on getting a null reference exception when trying to Mock a RestResponse.

Here is my unit test.

```
    [Test]
    public void GetAll_Method_Throws_exception_if_response_Data_is_Null()
    {
        var restClient = new Mock<IRestClient>();

        restClient.Setup(x => x.Execute(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
            .Returns(new RestResponse<RootObjectList>
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = null
            } );

        var client = new IncidentRestClient(restClient.Object);

        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => client.GetAll());
    }
```

Here is my actually implementation:

```
public class IncidentRestClient : IIncidentRestClient
{
    private readonly IRestClient client;
    private readonly string url = "some url here";

    public IncidentRestClient()
    {
        client = new RestClient { BaseUrl = new Uri(url) };
    }

    public RootObjectList  GetAll()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("api/now/table/incident", Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

        IRestResponse<RootObjectList> response = client.Execute<RootObjectList>(request);

        if (response.Data == null)
            throw new Exception(response.ErrorException.ToString());

        return response.Data;
    }
}
```

For some reason response object is null.  Could it be I'm mocking the return object incorrectly?

Comment: What is the "IncidentRestClient?" Is it a type you have defined?

Comment: Hi Sean. Yes, it's a type I've defined.. please see edit above.

Comment: It looks like the constructor of your `IncidentRestClient` doesn't take a `IRestClient` as a parameter. Is there another constructor defined that takes that parameter?

Answer (score 13):

For disclosure purposes, I am assuming that your IncidentRestClient has a constructor that takes an *IRestClient* instance as a parameter and uses it to set the *client* member.

It looks like, in your test, you are running Setup for a different overload of Execute than the one you are using. Instead of:

```
.Setup(x => x.Execute(
```

try:

```
.Setup(x => x.Execute<RootObjectList>(
```

Comment: Hi Sean. Thank you so much!!  :) I can't believe I overlooked this overload in the Setup.  I now get a RestReponse object back.

Comment: Yes, it has contructor                                                                        public IncidentRestClient(IRestClient client)
{
            this.client = client;
 }

Comment: @jaypman You should accept this answer if it was correct/helpful. An upvote would be nice to. That's how this works.

Comment: @ToddMenier I cannot upvote at the moment b/c it says I need at least 15 reputation points.